# Change Ctrl+Click Behavior in VS Output Window

Tags: visual-studio

Is there a way to change how links are opened from the **Output Window** (not an Editor)?

Meaning, when the Output Windows detects a link, it's Ctrl+Click-able and opens in an Internet Explorer tab.

I'd like to change the target from IE to the Text Editor and still within Visual Studio.

There are solutions for changing the click behavior in an Editor, but I am asking specifically about the Output Window.  I understand the answer might just be *no*.

Answer (score 0):

There's a Visual Studio Extension that lets you open URIs in the browser (https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/46c0c49e-f825-454b-9f6a-48b216797eb5).

I've forked it and made some updates so that it will handle `file:///` URIs as well, opening them in the Visual Studio editor or an external editor.  I've published a debug version that hasn't been very heavily tested [here](https://github.com/dnfield/OpenInExternalBrowser/releases/download/1.2.0/Tvl.VisualStudio.OpenInExternalBrowser.vsix).  You can peruse the full source of my fork [here](https://github.com/dnfield/OpenInExternalBrowser), or the original source [here](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/OpenInExternalBrowser/).

This makes debugging/working with the BizTalk map/schema tools a lot better...

Comment: Cool, since this question died, I also wrote my own VS extension that opens the 'most relevant' file in the output.

Comment: I was looking at going that direction - this extension will work besides just the output window, and for as many links as there are in the output window.  But it's probably not as useful outside the output window anyway.